# Unity detect image collision only OnEndDrag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I move an image around the screen with the mouse and place it where I want to. I have a panel at the bottom of the screen and I want to detect when the image is touching inside `OnEndDrag`

I know I can use

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) { 
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Panel") { 
        Destroy(gameObject); 
    } 
}
```

However I want to check inside:

```
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (this.gameObject.tag != "Clone")
    {
        transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

*** Update
I have update my code as per suggestion. However I have not been able to get the `Debug.Log("Image is over panel");` when I place the image over the panel. I have the script attached to the image and I have a Box Collider 2D on the panel.

```
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    //Getting corners of Image
    Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
    GetComponent<RectTransform>().GetWorldCorners(corners);

    Debug.Log("World Corners");
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("World Corner " + i + " : " + corners[i]);
    }

    var bottomLeft = corners[0];
    var topRight = corners[2];

    var panelCollider = Physics2D.OverlapArea(bottomLeft, topRight);

    if (panelCollider && panelCollider.gameObject.tag == "Panel")
    {
        Debug.Log("Image is over panel");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Physics` (or `Physics2D`) classes should help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use e.g. [`Physics2D.OverlapArea`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapArea.html) and for the points use e.g. [`RectTransform.GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) depending a lot on your setup ofcourse. Probably something like

```
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (gameObject.tag == "Clone") return;

    var corners = GetComponent<RectTransform>().GetWorldCorners();

    var bottomLeft = corners[0];
    var topRight = corners[2];

    var collider = Physics2D.OverlapArea(bottomLeft, topRight);

    if(collider && collider.gameObject.tag == "Panel")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }    
    else
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: I have used your answer as a guide and read the Unity reference docs. However I am confused I am checking the right values in the Image and the Panel. I have updated my question with the current code I am running. Appreciate if you could check, thanks